# How do I cancel an order programmatically with custom comments?

Tags: orders, model

I know one can call `$order->cancel()` to easily cancel an order, but it calls `registerCancellation()` which in turns calls the internal `_setState()` itself.

The internal `_setState()` function will add a state change history all on its own, provided with no way to customize it.

If I want that status changing history contains my own comments, or even notify customers, how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
if ($order->canCancel()) {
    try {
        $order->cancel();

        // remove status history set in _setState
        $order->getStatusHistoryCollection(true);

        // do some more stuff here
        // ...

        $order->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$order->getHistoryStatusCollection()->getLastItem()->delete()->save();` is exactly how I did this. Added that rewriting the whole order model would be the perfect solution, but I just don't bother.

Comment: Does it also reset the coupon code applied to it. If not then how to do it any idea

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this ?

```
$order->setData('state', "cancel");
    $order->setStatus("cancel");
    $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order marked as cancelled.', false);
    $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order->save();
```

Comment: AFAIK an order must call `registerCancellation()` to properly set prices, problem is that it contains a non-customizable `_setState()` call inside.